# Centering JQuery/UI objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, progress-bar, centering

I would like to center a [buttonset](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button) and a [progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) horizontally within their parent containers.
Trying to add a style `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` does not seem to work for me.
For a parent div to use this, the parent would need to be the same size as its child.
How can this be done?

Comment: It seems, `<div style="text-align:center;"></div>` as parent element does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
position: absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left: - <value>px;
```

here put the `value = half of width of button/progressbar`. if not any width given you do give a `width` to it using css `width: <your_width>px` . Do this individually for progressbar and button